# Using LINQ to SQl to achieve column Query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Can the below query be achieved with LINQ to SQL?

```
select id, 
      (select StateName from b_mstates where id=StateIdFk) as [State Name], 
      CityName 
from b_mcities
```

Comment: Yes, you just have to write it Linq style.

Comment: [Linqer | SQL to LINQ converter](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)

Comment: Have you started trying? If yes, then please add your code to question

Comment: I have not tried the answers. I will do that and get back. But in order to move forward, I created a View in MSSQL and queried it using LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = b_mcities.where(x => b_mstates.where(y => y.id == StateIdFK)
                                    .contains(x.statename)).ToList();
```

Your question is pretty tough, because your sql wont run(it is malformed and missing logic). this is the jist of what you will need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your associations set up correctly, it should be as simple as

```
var result = from city in m_bcities
             select new {city.id, city.State.StateName, city.CityName}
```